# Why does IObservable<T>.First() block?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I've been trying to get my head around the Reactive Extensions for .NET of late, but have hit a bit of a conceptual wall: I can't work out why IObservable.First() blocks.

I have some sample code that looks a bit like this:

```
var a = new ListItem(a);
var b = new ListItem(b);
var c = new ListItem(c);
var d = new ListItem(d);

var observableList = new List<ListItem> { a,b,c,d }.ToObservable();

var itemA = observableList.First();

// Never reached
Assert.AreEqual(expectedFoo, itemA.Foo);
```

What I was expecting to happen was for `itemA` to be referentially equal to `a` and to be able to access its members, etc.  What happens instead is that `First()` blocks and the `Assert.AreEqual()` is never reached.

Now, I know enough to know that when using Rx, code should `Subscribe()` to `IObservable`s, so it's likely that I've just done the wrong thing here.  However, it's not possible, based on the various method signatures to do either of:

```
observableList.First().Subscribe(item => Assert.AreEqual(expectedFoo, item));
```

or

```
observableList.Subscribe(SomeMethod).First() // This doesn't even make sense, right?
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'd expect this to work too - I'd expect it to subscribe immediately, wait for the first value to be pushed, and then unsubscribe. With an observable based on a collection, that should happen immediately. Hmm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`First()` returns a `T`, not an `Observable<T>`, so it must block.

A non-blocking form is `xs.Take(1)`

Answer (score 9):

Trying this code out in a test project worked fine, so I revisited the problematic code.  It turned out the problem was because the `IObservable<ListItem>` was being `Publish()`ed somewhere under the covers and so being converted into an `IConnectableObservable<ListItem>`.  Without a call to connect, the subscription was never "activated".

Comment: Your question is just a tad ambiguous. Scott Weinstein's answer is technically correct. First() is a blocking operator. In your case you expected your program to continue immediately because your Observable should yield values immediately on subscription, but First() should still be considered a blocking operator. Take(1).Subscribe(...) would give you the same behavior in a non-blocking form. Your observation about the ConnectableObservable is extremely helpful to others, though, so thanks for posting this.

Comment: Anderson Imes: thanks for the clear explanation. I have up-voted both your comment and @Scott Weinstein's answer as a result.